# Error! Unable to generate Contract ByteCode and ABI .help

Tags: solidity

```
  pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // '0GRS' token contract
    //
    // Deployed to : 0x5916c25e2a90aaA5b6aB5b6a328EA07DeF7c0cC7 
    // Symbol      : 0GRS
    // Name        : 0 Gorgeous Token
    // Total supply: 100000000
    // Decimals    : 18
    //
    // Enjoy.
    //
    // (c) by Moritz Neto with BokkyPooBah / Bok Consulting Pty Ltd Au 2017. The MIT Licence.
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Safe maths
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    contract SafeMath {
        function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
            c = a + b;
            require(c >= a);
        }
        function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
            require(b <= a);
            c = a - b;
        }
        function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
            c = a * b;
            require(a == 0 || c / a == b);
        }
        function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
            require(b > 0);
            c = a / b;
        }
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ERC Token Standard #20 Interface
    // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    contract ERC20Interface {
        function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint);
        function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance);
        function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining);
        function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
        function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);
        function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success);

        event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
        event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Contract function to receive approval and execute function in one call
    //
    // Borrowed from MiniMeToken
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    contract ApproveAndCallFallBack {
        function receiveApproval(address from, uint256 tokens, address token, bytes data) public;
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // Owned contract
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    contract Owned {
        address public owner;
        address public newOwner;

        event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed _from, address indexed _to);

        constructor() public {
            owner = msg.sender;
        }

        modifier onlyOwner {
            require(msg.sender == owner);
            _;
        }

        function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) public onlyOwner {
            newOwner = _newOwner;
        }
        function acceptOwnership() public {
            require(msg.sender == newOwner);
            emit OwnershipTransferred(owner, newOwner);
            owner = newOwner;
            newOwner = address(0);
        }
    }


    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // ERC20 Token, with the addition of symbol, name and decimals and assisted
    // token transfers
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    contract GorgeousToken is ERC20Interface, Owned, SafeMath {
        string public symbol;
        string public  name;
        uint8 public decimals;
        uint public _totalSupply;

        mapping(address => uint) balances;
        mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Constructor
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        constructor() public {
            symbol = "0GRS";
            name = "0 Gorgeous Token";
            decimals = 18;
            _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;
            balances[0x5916c25e2a90aaA5b6aB5b6a328EA07DeF7c0cC7] = _totalSupply;
            emit Transfer(address(0), 0x5916c25e2a90aaA5b6aB5b6a328EA07DeF7c0cC7, _totalSupply);
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Total supply
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function totalSupply() public constant returns (uint) {
            return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Get the token balance for account tokenOwner
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public constant returns (uint balance) {
            return balances[tokenOwner];
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Transfer the balance from token owner's account to to account
        // - Owner's account must have sufficient balance to transfer
        // - 0 value transfers are allowed
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
            balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
            balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
            emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
            return true;
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
        // from the token owner's account
        //
        // https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md
        // recommends that there are no checks for the approval double-spend attack
        // as this should be implemented in user interfaces 
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
            allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
            emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
            return true;
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Transfer tokens from the from account to the to account
        // 
        // The calling account must already have sufficient tokens approve(...)-d
        // for spending from the from account and
        // - From account must have sufficient balance to transfer
        // - Spender must have sufficient allowance to transfer
        // - 0 value transfers are allowed
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) {
            balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
            allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
            balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
            emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
            return true;
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Returns the amount of tokens approved by the owner that can be
        // transferred to the spender's account
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public constant returns (uint remaining) {
            return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Token owner can approve for spender to transferFrom(...) tokens
        // from the token owner's account. The spender contract function
        // receiveApproval(...) is then executed
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function approveAndCall(address spender, uint tokens, bytes data) public returns (bool success) {
            allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
            emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
            ApproveAndCallFallBack(spender).receiveApproval(msg.sender, tokens, this, data);
            return true;
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Don't accept ETH
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function () public payable {
            revert();
        }


        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Owner can transfer out any accidentally sent ERC20 tokens
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        function transferAnyERC20Token(address tokenAddress, uint tokens) public onlyOwner returns (bool success) {
            return ERC20Interface(tokenAddress).transfer(owner, tokens);
        }
    }
```

Contract Address 0x1b46656f3a5de413892a71f2266a42fafe6a6d89 help me
Compiler :0.4.24+commit.e67f0147

Comment: A bit more information might be helpful. Why are you not able to generate the ABI and byteCode? How are you trying to generate them???
The more you tell us, the more we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Must mention network name, found this Contract verified on EtherScan. Your Question is about How to get ABI and ByteCode ?

You can get by pasting this code in Remix, once compiled, select your desired contract you want to have ABI and ByteCode.
Moreover, heres in your contract CODE tab, you can see ByteCode details in your [Contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x1b46656f3a5de413892a71f2266a42fafe6a6d89#code)

Answer (score 0):

> Hi @DIMA, Just click on contract list as mentioned in image below:

[image]

> And Select GorgeousToken from list and then deploy.

[image]